# Integrate salesforce org into Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

How to integrate salesfroce org into Marketing Cloud without diconnect current connection to another Salesforce org and why should I disconnect current connection? Multi-org is enabled.[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can only connect one Salesforce org to one BU.

> Multi-org is a Marketing Cloud Enterprise 2.0 configuration. It allows
> individual Marketing Cloud business units to independently connect to
> a single Sales or Service Cloud account. Connected app authentication
> is required.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_marketing_cloud_connect_overview_faqs.htm&type=5

Comment: So, how should i need to avoid disconnect existing connection? i have 1 parent BU and 3 child BU. Parent BU is connected to Salesforce org. When i try to integrate another salesforce org to child BU, the marketing cloud settings required disconnect existing connection.